# How to edit my class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, oop, constructor

I'm learning OOP in C# and I get a problem during coding. I would like to create a class with constructor, which will read attributes by `Console.ReadLine`. Unfortunately, I get a strange error which I can't understand it.

This is my class:

```
public class Klasa
{
    int zarobki;
    string nazwisko;
    string stanowisko;
    public Klasa(string a, string b, string c)
    {
        a = (Console.ReadLine());
        b = (Console.ReadLine());
        c = (Console.ReadLine());
        zarobki = int.Parse(a);
        nazwisko = b;
        stanowisko = c;
    }
}
```

After compile, I got the following error:

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'a' of 'Klasa.Klasa(string, string,
>   string)'  ConsoleApplication17    c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication17\ConsoleApplication17\Program.cs    13  Active
>   ".

Answer (score 0):

You should call the constructor from some other place. Like this in a console application:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = (Console.ReadLine());
    var b = (Console.ReadLine());
    var c = (Console.ReadLine());
    Klasa k = new Klasa(a,b,c);
}
```

And then your class should be something like this:

```
public class Klasa
{
    int zarobki;
    string nazwisko;
    string stanowisko;
    public Klasa(string a, string b, string c)
    {
        zarobki = int.Parse(a);
        nazwisko = b;
        stanowisko = c;
    }
}
```

This solves your problem but you are structurally misguided. I think you should start by reading a book or an article before jumping into code.